# Dataflow job has stopped acknowledging any message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc-python

We've got a Dataflow pipeline where the input comes from a PubSub topic sending json objects.
The dataflow processes them with apache beam using a one-minute window to merge all the objects into one file every minute in a google cloud storage bucket.
Our Django application sends messages to the topics at all time (a few per second)
We haven't had any problem with it ever since we launched it a few months ago and it's been running perfectly with no change needed.
A few days ago I noticed that no new data was coming into the google cloud bucket.
We're still sending as many messages but none of them are being acknowledged.
After I updated/restarted the job, a few messages were processed and then it stopped again.
The messages are just piling up, unacked.
I've started a duplicate job that seems to be processing the messages so far.

Going into the logs I've seen several errors that I don't understand:

```
> Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
> CANCELLED: call already cancelled
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:107)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1363)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:153)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1086)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
> CANCELLED: call already cancelled
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:341)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.stream.DirectStreamObserver.onNext(DirectStreamObserver.java:98)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.flush(BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.java:100)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.accept(BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.java:112)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.data.RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.process(RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.java:203)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:107)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1363)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:153)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1086)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The apache beam code hasn't been updated in months.

```
Another error that I've found is the log is:
  message: "Error processing instruction -2893. Original traceback is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 421, in input_elements
    element = received.get(timeout=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 172, in get
    raise Empty
queue.Empty

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 245, in _execute
    response = task()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 302, in <lambda>
    lambda: self.create_worker().do_instruction(request), request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 471, in do_instruction
    getattr(request, request_type), request.instruction_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 506, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 961, in process_bundle
    expected_inputs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 424, in input_elements
    raise RuntimeError('Channel closed prematurely.')
RuntimeError: Channel closed prematurely.
```

There is also some other ones:

```
while getting AWS credentials NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
```

Which I found odd since we don't use AWS credentials but a GCP service account.

And another two errors:

```
"skipping pod synchronization - [container runtime status check may not have completed yet, PLEG is not healthy: pleg has yet to be successful]" 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 528, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 388, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 365, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1595935264.487688541","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3876,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487684094","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":263,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487682685","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":357,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487675071","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Misformatted domain name","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487651308","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Misformatted domain name","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244}]}]}]}]}"
>
"   
  job: "2020-07-28_04_18_12-1927008415124357720"   
  logger: "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py:535"   
  message: "Failed to read inputs in the data plane.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/data_plane.py", line 528, in _read_inputs
    for elements in elements_iterator:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 388, in __next__
    return self._next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 365, in _next
    raise self
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "DNS resolution failed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1595935264.487688541","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3876,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487684094","description":"Resolver transient failure","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolving_lb_policy.cc","file_line":263,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487682685","description":"DNS resolution failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/dns_resolver_ares.cc","file_line":357,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487675071","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Misformatted domain name","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1595935264.487651308","description":"C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS: Misformatted domain name","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/resolver/dns/c_ares/grpc_ares_wrapper.cc","file_line":244}]}]}]}]}"
>"
```

All of those errors are new.

I'm fairly new to GCP, Google Dataflow and Apache beam, this was my first apache beam script and it had been stable but debugging it has proven hard. I can't find related errors online, I've tried to get into the VM and debug there but I didn't get anywhere.

I'd be grateful if anyone had any insights on what's happening and what those errors means.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you explaining the case with the same problem given in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137834/add-exception-handling-on-window-apache-beam-job-in-python)? Just for a reference to the code example.

Comment: Yes both threads refer to the same issue. This thread was specifically for someone to help me understand what was going wrong, while the one you've linked was for some help in adding exception handling in apache-beam to help me debug this issue.

Comment: For me the explanation provided by @Yichi Zhang in the previous thread is quite decent here. Does the parallel job behave the same?