# Add exception handling on window apache beam job in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to add some exception handling on my apache beam process.

It runs on a streaming job on google cloud dataflow

It's a simple python-based window sliding that reads a json object, groups it and sends it back

It's been running successfully for months without any tweaking but has been stuck since a few days ago

Streaming jobs can apparently stall because of unhandled exception which I imagine is what's happening, probably because of a corrupt record

I figured I'd add some exception handling to log then discard the broken records and investigate afterwards

However, I'm not sure how to go about adding exception handling
The code is:

```
class GroupWindowsIntoBatches(beam.PTransform):
    """A composite transform that groups Pub/Sub messages based on publish
    time and outputs a list of dictionaries, where each contains one message.
    """
    def __init__(self, window_size):
        self.window_size = int(window_size.get() * 60)
    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (pcoll |
                "Window into Fixed Intervals" >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(self.window_size)) |
                "Add classname Key" >> beam.Map(lambda elem: (json.loads(ast.literal_eval(elem.decode("utf-8")))['dw_classname'], elem)) |
                "Groupby" >> beam.GroupByKey())
```

I'm not sure which part is failing, adding a simple try/except around the whole thing won't work as it seems to produce a Java error that I cannot catch that simply. I also would like to know which elements are causing an issue.

Here is the java traceback I'm trying to catch:

```
> Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
> CANCELLED: call already cancelled
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:184)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:107)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1363)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:153)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1086)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException:
> CANCELLED: call already cancelled
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:524)
> org.apache.beam.vendor.grpc.v1p26p0.io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:341)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.stream.DirectStreamObserver.onNext(DirectStreamObserver.java:98)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.flush(BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.java:100)
> org.apache.beam.sdk.fn.data.BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.accept(BeamFnDataSizeBasedBufferingOutboundObserver.java:112)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.data.RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.process(RemoteGrpcPortWriteOperation.java:203)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:107)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:120)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
> org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:134)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:49)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:201)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:159)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.fn.control.BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.execute(BeamFnMapTaskExecutor.java:123)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1363)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1100(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:153)
> org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$7.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1086)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The code is fairly straightforward but I don't see how to catch exceptions, I'm very new to apache-beam, if anyone has insight I'd be very grateful!

Comment: could you post the java error on the dataflow. It might give some clue

Comment: Good point Joss, I've just edited my post with the java traceback, thank you

Comment: What is your Apache Beam SDK version? Did the pipeline consume any message from Pub/Sub?

Comment: Does the exception only happen when dataflow tries to scale up/down the worker pool or it is persistent? The exception may happen when the vm is being shutdown prematurely but the unfinished work should be moved and retried on another worker.

Comment: @mk_sta my Apache Beam SDK version is Python 3.6,  2.21.0.
It used to consume messages then suddenly stopped and unacked messages started piling up. My theory was that it's a poison pill.

The exception is persistent

Comment: The java exception shouldn't be a poison pill (if the java process is unhealthy the whole vm will get re-launched), I'd suggest wrap the json.loads in a DoFn and except any errors   on malformatted data.

Comment: @Toussah, Do you have autoscaling enabled for this job? – mk_sta

Comment: I've left this setting with its default value. The documentation says that autoscaling is enabled by default for Batch job, I'm using a streaming job (without stream engine) so I assume it means autoscaling is not enabled by default. Although the documentation isn't very clear

Comment: I agree with @Yichi Zhang, as per Apache Beam documentation, you may try to adopt try-catch block in particular `DoFn`. Have you looked at this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54430640/9928809)?